# Problem with passing a vector as a binding to the for macro

Tags: binding, clojure, list-comprehension

I have an arbitrary number of lists which I would like to process using the for macro. I want to create a function that passes a vector as the binding since the number of lists varies.

If I hard code the binding, it works as I expect:

```
=> (def list1 '("pink" "green"))
=> (def list2 '("dog" "cat"))
=> (for [A list1 B list2] (str A "-" B))
("pink-dog" "pink-cat" "green-dog" "green-cat")
```

When I try to create a vector separately and use this as the binding I hit problems. Here I manually create the bindings vector:

```
=> (def testvector (vec (list 'A list1 'B list2)))
```

this seems fine:

```
=> testvector
[A ("pink" "green") B ("dog" "cat")]
=> (class testvector)
clojure.lang.PersistentVector
```

However,

```
=> (for testvector (str A "-" B))
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: for requires a vector for its binding (NO_SOURCE_FILE:36)>
```

I don't understand why testvector isn't considered a vector when used as the binding in for. Grasping at straws, I put testvector in square brackets which keeps the for macro happy (it sees a vector) but now I have a vector with one element (i.e. a vector within a vector) and this doesn't work because the binding needs to be pairs of name and collection.

```
=> (for [testvector] (str A "-" B))
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: for requires an even number of forms in binding vector (NO_SOURCE_FILE:37)>
```

Any suggestions on how to dynamically pass a vector as a binding to for would be appreciated.

Comment: (vec (list ...)) can be simpler written as (vector ...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is that *for* is a macro. At macro-expansion time, testvector is a symbol. It will evaluate to a vector at evaluation time, but it's not a vector from the perspective of the *for* macro.

```
user=> (defmacro tst [v] (vector? v))
#'user/tst
user=> (tst testvector)
false
user=> (vector? testvector)
true
user=> (defmacro tst2 [v] `(vector? ~v))
#'user/tst2
user=> (tst2 testvector)
true
```

If you check the source for the *for* macro (in core.clj), you'll see that *for* uses an unquoted *vector?* call, just like *tst* in the example above.

Comment: For those of us that are still learning Clojure, what is the next step to actually make it work? I've tried (defmacro combo [v] `(for ~v [A B])) and it does not work with the same error message about _for_ needing a vector

Comment: @JonathanBenn Yes, even if you wrap _for_ in a macro, it itself is still a macro and the same limitations apply. This answer isn't a solution, just an explanation why it won't work. A clever macro-time solution is escaping me at the moment, but I think you could solve the OP's test problem with a recursive function.

Comment: Thanks. I've been struggling to find a solution but my Clojure-fu is not advanced enough. I'll try your suggestion of a recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to force the evaluation of the binding vector. Instead of trying to define a macro that will wrap the `for` macro, wrap it in a function, e.g.

```
(defn for-fn [bindings expr]
  (eval `(for ~bindings ~expr)))
```

Then you can actually build a binding vector with a few additional constraints since all s-expressions inside the binding vector need to be valid and contain a verb as the first element.

```
(let [bindings '[a (list 1 2) b (list 3 4) c (range 10 12)
                 :when (> (+ a b c) 15)]
      expr '(str a "-" b "-" c)]
  (for-fn bindings expr))
```

And with your example :

```
(def list1 '("pink" "green"))
(def list2 '("dog" "cat"))
(def testvector (vector 'A (cons 'list  list1) 'B (cons 'list list2)))

(for-fn testvector '(str A "-" B))
=> ("pink-dog" "pink-cat" "green-dog" "green-cat")
```

Note : since `for-fn` is function, you need to quote the expression `(str A "-" B)` to prevent an early evaluation (before A & B are bound).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method of last resort. Be warned, wherever you see `read-string` that is code for *Here Be Dragons!* (Due to security risks, and lack of compile-time consistency guarantees about the behaviour of your code)

```
(def list1 '("pink" "green"))
(def list2 '("dog" "cat"))
(for [A list1 B list2] (str A "-" B))

(def testvector (vec (list 'A list1 'B list2)))

(def testvector-vec (vec (list 'A (vec list1) 'B (vec list2))))

(def for-string (str "(for " testvector-vec "(str A \"-\" B))"))

(eval (read-string for-string))
> ("pink-dog" "pink-cat" "green-dog" "green-cat")
```

Comment: Don't use strings to manipulate any code in a lisp. This is a lisp, so you could just do `(eval \`(for ~testvector-vec (str ~'A "-" ~'B)))`

Answer (score 0):

Although not a solution to your problem, it should be noted that what you are doing can more easily be achieved with map rather than for e.g.

```
user=> (def list1 '("pink" "green"))
#'user/list1
user=> (def list2 '("dog" "cat"))
#'user/list2
user=> (map #(str %1 "-" %2) list1 list2)
("pink-dog" "green-cat")
user=>
```

Another useful technique when learning and experimenting is to use keywords rather than strings. This can reduce typing i.e. no need to put the values in quotes and can sometimes help identify errors more easily. Instead of (def list1 '("pink" "green")) you can just do (def list1 '(:pink :green)). Even better, rather than using lists, try using vectors and then you don't have to quote it (saving another keystroke).